# How to call wordpress custom post type page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

i make a custom post type in WordPress  and i also make its separate two pages single-acme_product.php, archive-acme_product.php but the issue is when i upload the post from custom post type its show index.php

here is my code of function

```
function new_post_type_wp(){

    register_post_type('acme_product',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __('Products'),
                    'singular_name' => __('Product')
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
            )
        );
}
add_action('init','new_post_type_wp');
```

please tell me how to i navigate my custom post to specific custom page i also read wordpress codex its very help full i follow its method but my issue is same kindly help me

reference link : https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: Please re-save your permalinks. Settings > Permalinks > Save.

Comment: no its not the issue i did it but the result is same

Comment: Have you tried using a core-bundled theme to be sure some code elsewhere in your theme is not causing the issue?

Comment: No I no try this May b this possible I implement this on another theme and tell you what the status

Comment: @Milo thanks dear your point out exact issue i perform this on default template and its work on default template then i copy paste the code its work not know what happen but i am happy thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since WordPress is having trouble recognizing your custom template files, you could use this instead.

Insert into your `single.php` file. Based on your description above, it sounds like you don't have a `single.php` file so you will likely have to create one. If you do already have a `single.php` file then there is likely still some confusion with your exact problem because a custom post would only display the `index.php` template if there was no `single.php`. Or you could just be confusing the two.

```
<?php 
  if( get_post_type == 'acme_product' ) {
    // Put the template code to display the custom post type post

  } else {
    // Code for all other posts

  }
?>
```

This will work in any of the default WordPress post related template files like categories, archives, etc.

Comment: it's probably better to figure out why something that should be working isn't working.

Comment: Agreed, but I'd like to provide him with the option just in case. I am hoping someone has another idea to solve his problem.

Answer (score -3):

Alright, if I am not wrong with your request, below solutions may help.
1. make you sing-acme_product.php as a template, eg:

```
   <?php
   /**
   Template Name: the new of the template
   */
```

2. Use WP_Query, eg:

   $products = new WP_Query('post_type = products'); 
   if($products->have_posts()) : while($products->have_posts()):$products->the_post();

   endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();

Hope this will help.

Comment: dear i make a custom post type and i just want i show my custom posts on single-acme_product.php , the issue i make a separate page single-acme_product.php for custom posts reference link codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types but instead the posts show on single-acme_product.php they show on index.php i just want to show these post on my single-acme_product.php you got it ??

Comment: Why do you want to do this, it will complicate things even more, and btw, how will you handle single posts